# Delphi clone layout

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have made an android app with Delphi but I have a weird behavior. This is the situation.

[image]

I have a TLayout (called InputLayout) and it contains a `GridPanelLayout`. I have to copy this grid inside the InputLayout but I get this result:

[image]

Of course the result that I have is the one on the left. You can see that this is **not** what I am looking for because I would like to have an exact copy of the grid above. The final result must be two GridPanelLayout where the second is placed below the first. This is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var c: TGridPanelLayout;
begin

 try

  c := TGridPanelLayout(InputLayout.Children[0].Clone(InputLayout));
  c.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
  InputLayout.AddObject(c);

 except

  // ... 

 end;

end;
```

What is wrong? Please note that `InputLayout` is the layout that contains the GridPanelLayout and that component is the only one, so I can access safely with the 0 index.

Comment: The design time `GridPanelLayout` doesn't appear to be aligned to the top. It is unclear how many columns and rows the `GridPanelLayout` has. When I try your issue (with 3 columns, 1 row and the first `GridPanelLayout` aligned to top), I do get some drawing artefacts which disappear if I minimize and restore the form. Try what happens for you and add to your question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes it is aligned to top (the one inside the layout at design time). Do I have to put the cloned one to TAlignLayout.Top as well? I am using that code but even if I resize the page that won't work. Could that be a bug?

Comment: I think I have found a solution but it works with a TGridLayout. For some reasons a GridPanelLayout doesn't work very well and I have the same behavior as @TomBrunberg.

Comment: I don't care, I just need my problem to be solved.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the `GridPanelLayout` doesn't seem to behave as (probably) intended. There are 14 open QP entries, some affects your project. You are correct in the anchors of the cloned `GridPanelLayout`s unexpectedly do not catch. I suggest you try a workaround, create at design time sufficiently with `GridPanelLayout`s and hide / show as needed by setting the `Visible` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you cannot use a `TGridPanelLayout` because it seems that there is something wrong with that component. I am using Delphi Tokyo Starter and I have found this solution to your problem.

1. Drop a VertScrollBox (or a TLayout or a HorzScrollBox)
2. Put a `TGridLayout` outside the the VertScrollBox
3. Add in the GridLayout what you need for example a `TEdit` or a `TLabel`
4. Set `TGridLayout.Visible := false;` because you are using this as "template". I will make a copy of this and the clone will be added in the InputLayout.

A `TGridLayout` works on Windows but I guess that it will work on Android and iOS as well (I can't test it with starter). Add an event handler to a button like this:

```
//Button1 onclick
for i := 1 to max do
   begin
    c := (GridLayout1.Clone(Owner) as TGridLayout);
    (c as TGridLayout).Visible := True;
    (c as TGridLayout).Parent := InputLayout;
    InputLayout.AddObject(c);
   end;
```

Here there is an integer variable called `max` which of course indicates how many children you are going to create inside `InputLayout`. It isn't really needed if you have to make a single copy, but I am giving you this loop just in case you change your mind. Here you have the result:

[image]

Here you see 3 `TEdit` components but you had a `TLabel`, a `TEdit` and a `TButton`. What to do? Simply revert the TGridLayout visibility to True, add whatever you want (in this case a label, an edit and a button) and set the `Visible` poperty to false again.

Comment: I have understood, I had in mind to do something like that using another component. Yes the loop is useless because I didn't ask for it in the op but good solution anyway. I hope they will fix this bug...